# How can I get my total calculation to work when I have multiple dropdown menus on a page and need to total all of the results? Do I need a 0 default?

Tags: javascript

I have 5 dropdown menus on my page with results that populate depending on the option selected. I need to total the results of those 5 dropdowns as well. I need the total to work even if someone doesn't choose all of the options. Currently I get an answer when all of the options are selected, but the answer isn't correct. When I don't choose an option for each one, I get the NaN result.

I'm wondering if first it would work better if I have a "0" default option for each dropdown menu when the page is loaded? I tried to figure out how to do that by giving the first option a value of "0", but it wasn't showing up even when I changed option selected to option value. I realized after I did that, it wouldn't work anyway since I still wasn't selecting anything. I also couldn't figure out in my javascript how to get "0" to automatically pop up with how I setup my code. I ran the code in codepen and didn't get any errors, so I'm stuck. Any help getting the total impact fees to work no matter what options are chosen would be amazing!

```js
var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownRoadsTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownRoads").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("roadsanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownFireTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownFire").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("fireanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownEMSTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownEMS").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("EMSanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownSchoolsTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownSchools").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("schoolsanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownParksTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownParks").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("parksanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function add() {
  var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("roadsanswer").value);
  num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fireanswer").value);
  num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("EMSanswer").value);
  num4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("schoolsanswer").value);
  num5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("parksanswer").value);
  sum = Math.abs(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("answer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="450" align="center" valign="top">
      <div align="left" class="body" valign="top">
        <p>
          <font color="#FC030B">Enter value using the following format: </font>
        </p>
        <p>
          <font color="#FC030B">Residential: Whole number per unit (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 10, 24, etc.)</font>
        </p>
        <p>
          <font color="#FC030B">Commercial: Decimal per sf (e.g. 1,580sf = 1.580) / no comma</font>
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <div align="left" class="body">
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" id="Value" /></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
      <p class="body">Roads: Category<br><br> </p>
      <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <select name="roads" id="dropdownRoads" onchange="dropDownRoadsTotalHandler()" />
        <option selected="selected">Select Your Roads Category</option>
        <option value="12350">RES: Single-family residence, detached (per dwelling)</option>
        <option value="9576">RES: Multi-family or timeshare (per unit)</option>
        <option value="6541">RES: Mobile home/RV park (per pad)</option>
        <option value="2641">RES: Adult congregate living facility (ACLF) (per unit)</option>
        <option value="3138">RES: Continuing care retirement community (per unit)</option>
        <option value="6111">RES: Hotel / Motel (per room/unit)</option>
        <option value="14180">Shopping Center (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="31601">Bank (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="7551">Car Wash, self-service (per stall)</option>
        <option value="28755">Car Wash, semi-automated (per tunnel)</option>
        <option value="23449">Super convenience store with gas sales less than 10 fuel positions (per fuel position)</option>
        <option value="16759">Super convenience store with gas sales 10+ fuel positions (per fuel position)</option>
        <option value="2815">Golf course, open to public (per acre)</option>
        <option value="33335">Movie theater, stand-alone (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="27204">Restaurant, standard (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="60423">Restaurant, drive-through (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="9406">Office, general (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="9783">Office, medical (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="9783">Hospital (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="6061">Nursing home (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="5821">Place of Worship (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="12784">Day Care center</option>
        <option value="4811">Elementary/Secondary School, private (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="5432">Public / Institutional (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="4177">Industrial Park of General Industrial (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="2161">Warehouse (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="1739">Warehouse, high-cube (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="1341">Min-warehouse (per 1,000sf)</option>
        <option value="50">Mine or Quarry (per 1,000 cubic yards)</option>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <p class="body">Roads: Fee<br><br> $
        <input type="text" id="roadsanswer" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
      <p class="body">Fire: Category<br><br></p>
      <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <select name="roads" id="dropdownFire" onchange="dropDownFireTotalHandler()" />
        <option selected="selected">Select Your Fire Category</option>
        <option value="766">Single Family Residence</option>
        <option value="582">Multi-Family</option>
        <option value="559">Mobile Home / RV</option>
        <option value="368">Hotel / Motel</option>
        <option value="820">Retail</option>
        <option value="398">Office</option>
        <option value="237">Public or Institutional Use</option>
        <option value="146">General Industrial</option>
        <option value="84">Public / Private Warehouse</option>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <p class="body">Fire: Fee<br><br> $
        <input type="text" id="fireanswer" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
      <p class="body">EMS: Category<br><br> </p>
      <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <select name="roads" id="dropdownEMS" onchange="dropDownEMSTotalHandler()" />
        <option selected="selected">Select Your EMS Category</option>
        <option value="55">Single Family Residence</option>
        <option value="42">Multi-Family</option>
        <option value="40">Mobile Home / RV</option>
        <option value="26">Hotel / Motel</option>
        <option value="59">Retail</option>
        <option value="29">Office</option>
        <option value="17">Public or Institutional Use</option>
        <option value="10">General Industrial</option>
        <option value="6">Public / Private Warehouse</option>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <p class="body">EMS: Fee<br><br> $
        <input type="text" id="EMSanswer" /> </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
      <p class="body">Schools: Category<br><br></p>
      <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <select name="roads" id="dropdownSchools" onchange="dropDownSchoolsTotalHandler()" />
        <option selected="selected">Select Your Schools Category</option>
        <option value="3016.20">Single Family Residence</option>
        <option value="1167.65">Multi-Family</option>
        <option value="650.10">Mobile Home / RV</option>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <p class="body">Schools: Fee<br><br> $
        <input type="text" id="schoolsanswer" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
      <p class="body">Parks: Category<br><br></p>
      <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <select name="roads" id="dropdownParks" onchange="dropDownParksTotalHandler()" />
        <option selected="selected">Select Your Parks Category</option>
        <option value="912">Single Family (per dwelling)</option>
        <option value="690">Multi-Family, Duplex, Townhouse, Two-Family (per dwelling)</option>
        <option value="912">Mobile Home - not in MH park (per dwelling)</option>
        <option value="668">Mobile Home - in MH park (per pad)</option>
        <option value="668">RV park site (per pad)</option>
        <option value="436">Hotel/Model (per room)</option>
        <option value="690">Timeshare (per dwelling)</option>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
      <p class="body">Parks: Fee<br><br> $
        <input type="text" id="parksanswer" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left">
      <button onclick="add()" class="body">Calculate</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="450" align="center" valign="bottom">
      <div align="left" class="body">Total Impact Fees:</div>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="bottom" class="body">
      <p class="body">$ <input type="text" id="answer" /></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Aside from your question, tables shouldn't be used for styling

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

1. Add `required` attribute to every `<select>`
2. Add `value=""` to default `<option>`s
3. Wrap everything with `<form>` and listen for `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`. Remember to `preventDefault`

```js
var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownRoadsTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownRoads").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("roadsanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownFireTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownFire").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("fireanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownEMSTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownEMS").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("EMSanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownSchoolsTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownSchools").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("schoolsanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

var dropdownTotal = 0;

function dropDownParksTotalHandler() {
  var num1, num2, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Value").value);
  num2 = document.getElementById("dropdownParks").value;
  sum = Math.abs(num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("parksanswer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function add(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (!event.target.checkValidity()) return
  var num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, sum;
  num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("roadsanswer").value);
  num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fireanswer").value);
  num3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("EMSanswer").value);
  num4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("schoolsanswer").value);
  num5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("parksanswer").value);
  sum = Math.abs(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("answer").value = sum
    .toString()
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return false
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="add(event)">
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="450" align="center" valign="top">
        <div align="left" class="body" valign="top">
          <p>
            <font color="#FC030B">Enter value using the following format: </font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font color="#FC030B">Residential: Whole number per unit (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 10, 24, etc.)</font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font color="#FC030B">Commercial: Decimal per sf (e.g. 1,580sf = 1.580) / no comma</font>
          </p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <div align="left" class="body">
          <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text" id="Value" /></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
        <p class="body">Roads: Category<br><br> </p>
        <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
          <select required name="roads" id="dropdownRoads" onchange="dropDownRoadsTotalHandler()" />
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Roads Category</option>
          <option value="12350">RES: Single-family residence, detached (per dwelling)</option>
          <option value="9576">RES: Multi-family or timeshare (per unit)</option>
          <option value="6541">RES: Mobile home/RV park (per pad)</option>
          <option value="2641">RES: Adult congregate living facility (ACLF) (per unit)</option>
          <option value="3138">RES: Continuing care retirement community (per unit)</option>
          <option value="6111">RES: Hotel / Motel (per room/unit)</option>
          <option value="14180">Shopping Center (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="31601">Bank (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="7551">Car Wash, self-service (per stall)</option>
          <option value="28755">Car Wash, semi-automated (per tunnel)</option>
          <option value="23449">Super convenience store with gas sales less than 10 fuel positions (per fuel position)</option>
          <option value="16759">Super convenience store with gas sales 10+ fuel positions (per fuel position)</option>
          <option value="2815">Golf course, open to public (per acre)</option>
          <option value="33335">Movie theater, stand-alone (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="27204">Restaurant, standard (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="60423">Restaurant, drive-through (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="9406">Office, general (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="9783">Office, medical (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="9783">Hospital (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="6061">Nursing home (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="5821">Place of Worship (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="12784">Day Care center</option>
          <option value="4811">Elementary/Secondary School, private (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="5432">Public / Institutional (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="4177">Industrial Park of General Industrial (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="2161">Warehouse (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="1739">Warehouse, high-cube (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="1341">Min-warehouse (per 1,000sf)</option>
          <option value="50">Mine or Quarry (per 1,000 cubic yards)</option>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <p class="body">Roads: Fee<br><br> $
          <input type="text" id="roadsanswer" /></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
        <p class="body">Fire: Category<br><br></p>
        <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
          <select required name="roads" id="dropdownFire" onchange="dropDownFireTotalHandler()" />
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Fire Category</option>
          <option value="766">Single Family Residence</option>
          <option value="582">Multi-Family</option>
          <option value="559">Mobile Home / RV</option>
          <option value="368">Hotel / Motel</option>
          <option value="820">Retail</option>
          <option value="398">Office</option>
          <option value="237">Public or Institutional Use</option>
          <option value="146">General Industrial</option>
          <option value="84">Public / Private Warehouse</option>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <p class="body">Fire: Fee<br><br> $
          <input type="text" id="fireanswer" /></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
        <p class="body">EMS: Category<br><br> </p>
        <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
          <select required name="roads" id="dropdownEMS" onchange="dropDownEMSTotalHandler()" />
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your EMS Category</option>
          <option value="55">Single Family Residence</option>
          <option value="42">Multi-Family</option>
          <option value="40">Mobile Home / RV</option>
          <option value="26">Hotel / Motel</option>
          <option value="59">Retail</option>
          <option value="29">Office</option>
          <option value="17">Public or Institutional Use</option>
          <option value="10">General Industrial</option>
          <option value="6">Public / Private Warehouse</option>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <p class="body">EMS: Fee<br><br> $
          <input type="text" id="EMSanswer" /> </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
        <p class="body">Schools: Category<br><br></p>
        <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
          <select required name="roads" id="dropdownSchools" onchange="dropDownSchoolsTotalHandler()" />
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Schools Category</option>
          <option value="3016.20">Single Family Residence</option>
          <option value="1167.65">Multi-Family</option>
          <option value="650.10">Mobile Home / RV</option>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <p class="body">Schools: Fee<br><br> $
          <input type="text" id="schoolsanswer" /></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="36" align="left" valign="top">
        <p class="body">Parks: Category<br><br></p>
        <div align="left" valign="top" class="body">
          <select required name="roads" id="dropdownParks" onchange="dropDownParksTotalHandler()" />
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Your Parks Category</option>
          <option value="912">Single Family (per dwelling)</option>
          <option value="690">Multi-Family, Duplex, Townhouse, Two-Family (per dwelling)</option>
          <option value="912">Mobile Home - not in MH park (per dwelling)</option>
          <option value="668">Mobile Home - in MH park (per pad)</option>
          <option value="668">RV park site (per pad)</option>
          <option value="436">Hotel/Model (per room)</option>
          <option value="690">Timeshare (per dwelling)</option>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" class="body">
        <p class="body">Parks: Fee<br><br> $
          <input type="text" id="parksanswer" /></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left">
        <button class="body">Calculate</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="450" align="center" valign="bottom">
        <div align="left" class="body">Total Impact Fees:</div>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="bottom" class="body">
        <p class="body">$ <input type="text" id="answer" /></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

on function **add()**
you need to add condition (if) like this

```
if(isNaN(num1) || isNan(num2) || isNaN(num3) || isNaN(num4) || isNaN(num5) ){
//alert here
}
```

this is for checking if num1...num5 you mention earlier are NaN

detail here
[here](https://codepen.io/gundambison/pen/eYLMYog?editors=1111)

if you need num1 is not selected but return as 0. You must added condition like this

```
if( isNaN(num1)) num1=0;
```

if you solve this problem. Next suggestion is to make readable and clean script. It help a lot on debugging